# Не переходит на второй Фрагмент

Tags: java, android

У меня есть 4 фрагмента, и для примера с одними TextView переходят нормально. И стоит мне добавить ListView с адаптером... То все кроме этой страницы никуда не переходит.

**Сам Код:**

```
public class ExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_example);
}

public void homeClick(View view) {
    Fragment myfragment;
    myfragment = new HomeFragment();
    Log.d("fragment changed", "");
    fragmentCommit(myfragment);
}

public void favClick(View view) {
    Fragment myfragment;
    myfragment = new FavFragment();
    Log.d("fragment changed", "");
    fragmentCommit(myfragment);
}

public void ssClick(View view) {
    Fragment myfragment;
    myfragment = new SsFragment();
    Log.d("fragment changed", "");
    fragmentCommit(myfragment);
}

public void rubClick(View view) {
    Fragment myfragment;
    myfragment = new RubFragment();
    Log.d("fragment changed", "");

    fragmentCommit(myfragment);
}

public void fragmentCommit(Fragment fragment){
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_switch, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
}
```

**Контейнер:**

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_switch"
    android:name="com.isakovch.Example.HomeFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout2" />
```

**HomeFragment:**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

List<VacancyModel> vacancyModelList;
public static List<VacancyModel> vacancyModelList2;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvMain);

    MainVacancyAdapter adapter;
    if (getActivity().getIntent().getBooleanExtra(SplashScreen.DATA_FROM_SPLASH_SCREEN, true)) {
        Bundle bundle = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        vacancyModelList = (List<VacancyModel>) bundle.getSerializable(VacancyModel.class.getCanonicalName());
        vacancyModelList2 = vacancyModelList;
        //Creating an adapter and setting it to the list
        adapter = new MainVacancyAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_main_vacancies, vacancyModelList);
    } else {
        //Creating an adapter and setting it to the list
        adapter = new MainVacancyAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_main_vacancies, vacancyModelList2);
    }
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return rootView;
}
}
```

**А остальные пустые, вроде этого:**

```
public class FavFragment extends Fragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fav, container,false);

}
}
```

В чем проблема, подскажите, везде перерыл?

Кстати, если тот же код ListView с адаптером перенести на FavFragment или на другие фрагменты работает нормально...

Comment: а как вы вызываете favClick , ssClick ... Где код активити?

Comment: В XML прописываю где onClick... Обновил код...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените `<fragment />` на какой-нибудь контейнер-наследник ViewGroup. Например, `<FrameLayout />`

Comment: Теперь автоматически не показывает первым HomeFragment

Comment: В onCreate() вашей активити добавьте в конец fragmentCommit( new HomeFragment() );

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо, заработало!!!!